# What is the smallest angle which has an algebraic sine and cosine.

Tags: trigonometry

I was wondering which the smallest angle is that has an constructable (non-zero) expression sine and cosine. 
$$$$1) If the expression for sine is constructable, then by: $cos(x)=\sqrt {1-sin^2(x)}$ the expression for the cosine is also constructable.
$$$$2) we are excluding 2 from this question, since we can use the half angle formula for sine and cosine to always half an angle. Else this would mean that an angle of $\frac{360}{2^n}$ for an arbitrary large n would be a possible answer. 
$$$$

I am asking this question since I recently discovered that a 17-gon (Heptadecagon) has a rational expression for its side length: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptadecagon. Thus I was wondering if there are any other angles that we know the constructable expression of. 
$$$$
I also came up with a way of solving for sin($\frac{2\pi}{255}$°)
$$sin(360°/17)=sin((21+\frac{3}{17})°)$$
$$sin((21+\frac{3}{15}-21)°)=sin((21+\frac{3}{17})°)\times cos(21°)+cos((21+\frac{3}{17})°) \times sin(21°)$$
since sin($\frac{2\pi}{255}$) = sin($\frac{360°}{255}$) = sin($\frac{3°}{17}$)

Comment: You should probably include the word "nonzero" somewhere in your question, since otherwise the smallest such angle is zero. // Also, you seem to be mixing up [algebraic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number) and [constructible numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_number), but they are not the same: trisecting an angle also results in algebraic sines and cosines, but they are not constructible.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, Whilst researching this question, I found the answer to it. There are 31 different constructable polygons with an odd amount of edges. The polygon with the most edges has 4.294.967.295 edges. ($3 \times 5 \times 17 \times 257 \times 65537$). The only way that there could be a polygon with more edges is, if there are more primes of the form $2^{2^n}+1$, (Fermat-Primes).

Comment: Of course, constructing an angle measuring $2\pi/65537$might not work well with the limited accuracy of drafting equipment.  $2\pi/257$ could be a problem, too.